# Removing blue "TLS 1.0 disablement" header permanently from help pages

Tags: help

Any tips?

When i click to close it, and reload the page, the blue header appears again. It is at every help page. I need to close it every time to be-able to read the first lines. I've already disabled TLS 1.0, and I'm logged in so Salesforce should be aware of this.

I'm not looking for something overly complicated. I just hope there is a setting somewhere.

Thanks!

[image: TLS 1.0 securidy warning]

Answer (score 0):

I mentioned is on the succes community a few days ago and Salesforce changed the behavior :D. Now when you close them they stay closed.